# Installation of CRM 2015 on windows 2016 servers

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2015, windows-server-2016

Is the CRM 2015 compatibles with windows server 2016 standard 64 bit?
One of the servers is running SQL server 2014 and I want the other one to run the front end and back end of the CRM.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is no.

[Software requirements for Microsoft Dynamics CRM Server 2015](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2015/deployment-administrators-guide/hh699671(v=crm.7))

> Microsoft Dynamics CRM Server 2015 can be installed only on Windows
>   Server 2012 64-bit-based computers.